# Correct way to handle any error with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am using mongoose to connect to a MongoDB Atlas cluster using the below to start the connection.
However when the connection fails it crashes the whole app and i have to restart it again.
Can anyone tell me the correct way to handle errors with the mongoose connection string in such a way that it leaves the rest of the app running and still listening on my port.
I dont want to worry about re-connecting to mongo in this function if it fails to connect.

```
  console.log("attempting to connect to MongoDB");
      mongoose.connect(connectString)
            .then((result)=>console.log("Connected to db"))
            .catch((err) => {
                            console.log(err);   
                            return next;                                                
                          }            
            )
```

Comment: try to just don't return next in catch.

Comment: nothing in that code would crash the server

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone - It works fine when I am not behind my companies strict firewall but crashes when i run it as a localhost from behind it. The logged error is that it could not connect to any servers in my mongoDB atlas cluster.
The point was though what ever the error should be i want it to carry on.
I get [nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting... when I run it from behind the firewall and have to restart the app

Comment: @turivishal - I took that out but it doesnt help

Comment: one more thing i missed, put an error event after your connection code, 
 `mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => { mongoose.disconnect(); });`

Comment: if nodemon crashed its not due to the code above, what's the exact error you getting? your app cant run without a db connection, so you need to add in place anywhere that uses the connection a check before calling methods doing queries on a connection which doesn't exist and stuff

Comment: @turivishal Would I put that in my catch part of my function?

Comment: no, put it after the connection code.

Comment: @Lawrence Cherone The full error message is too long to post on here - is there another way i can show it to you?

Answer (score 0):

Use an *Error event* after your connection

```
var mongoDB = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/theni';
mongoose.connect(mongoDB, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
});

//Get the default connection
var con = mongoose.connection;

//Bind connection to error event (to get notification of connection errors)
con.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'MongoDB connection error:'));
```